# how to add bitmap image to int array

Tags: java, android

I stored the images from drawable folder in the int array
       this is main activity

```
int[]image={R.drawable.screen1,R.drawable.screen2,R.drawable.screen3};
```

and i have bitmap image in the second activity

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream  b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     b1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, b);
     l2.putExtra("img1", b.toByteArray());
```

now how to add this bitmap to int image in main activity,then how to delete the image in the array.

Comment: You can't add the bitmap to drawable because you can't change the files once app is installed but u cant save it to another location and use it.

Comment: `I stored the images` you stored the IDs of images, not the images. `add this bitmap to int image` you can't

Comment: ok, can  u sugggest alternate method to deal this problam

Comment: depends on what you want to do with it

Comment: i want to display a images in recycler view ,so i want to intial have some images, in each row has button change image, and generall button to a new row in recycle view with new image either by camera or from gallery i had done recycler view ,gettting image but i do not how to store image bitmap from camera or gallery in int array before but now u said that  cannot do that. then how to do it

Comment: pls help me to complete the task